# Return xdmp:sql() values in CSV format XQuery

Tags: sql, csv, xquery, marklogic

How can we return xdmp:sql() values as csv (comma-delimited) results?
This is what I have tried to do so far:

```
(: The "format" option returns queries delimited with | :)

(: In other words this would return something like this:
    | foo| boo|
    | 1| 2|
:)
(: We want this:
    foo,boo
    1,2
:)
let $x := xdmp:sql("SELECT foo, boo FROM TableName", "format")
let $res :=
 for $item in $res
 let $newItem := fn:replace(xs:string($item), "\|", ",")
 return $newItem
return $res

(:returns:
  , foo, boo,
  , 1, 2,
:)
(: too many commas and whitespaces :)
```

My question is if there is an easier way to do this (as in if XQuery or MarkLogic provide a SQL to CSV function) besides manually changing it to csv format and if there isn't, what would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

One alternative that should work for SQL, SPARQL, or Optic is to quote with the "sparql-results-csv" output method as in:

```
xdmp:quote(
    xdmp:sql("SELECT foo, boo FROM TableName"),
    map:entry("method", "sparql-results-csv")
    )
```

Also, the `/v1/rows` endpoint of the REST API can return CSV responses for Optic queries. An Optic query can execute SQL via the op:from-sql() accessor or SPARQL via the op:from-sparql() accessor.

For more information, see

- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/langoverview#id_71572
- http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:quote
- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_54333

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward and naive approach would be to use this:

```
let $res := xdmp:sql("SELECT foo, boo FROM TableName", "array")
for $row in $res
let $values := json:array-values($row) ! xs:string(.)
return string-join($values, ',')
```

Don't capture all lines in a variable to string-join for line-feeds, just return as directly as possible. MarkLogic will automatically separate the lines with a line-feed. This will ensure streaming, so you can go up to a couple of million lines easily.

It doesn't scale well though, and to produce a fully correct CSV, you'd have to potentially escape cell values.

HTH!

Comment: This solution actually produces an error on the first argument of fn:string-join(), saying that $row is not a xs:string, and when you cast it, it then produces another error saying that it is not possible to cast $row to a string.

Comment: You are right. I forgot it returns a sequence of json:arrays, which in turn could contain non-strings as well. Let me edit the answer..

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found that this solution works best in producing a CSV output:

```
let $res := xdmp:sql("SELECT foo, boo FROM TableName", "map")
for $key in map:keys($res)
let $val := map:get($res, $key)
return fn:string-join(($key, $val), ",")
```

By iterating over the keys in a map, it was simple to just get the key and the value and then separate each key and value pair by a comma.

Comment: Your approach causes columns to be printed as rows, and $val could potentially contain non-strings, causing string-join to break. You might find the changes I made to my answer useful..